# Objective c comparing strings multiple words

Tags: objective-c, string, comparison

Hi I'm looking to compare 2 strings using objective c. One string is a single word and the other will be one or more words. How can I cheeck for a match at word level? I.e if any word from the multiple word string matches my single word string return a 1 else return a 0 ? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might be tempted to use `-[NSString rangeOfString:]`:

```
if ([multipleWords rangeOfString:singleWord].location != NSNotFound)
    return YES;
return NO;
```

But it's imperfect. You could have "returning" in `multipleWords` and `singleWord` could be "return", giving you a false positive.

So instead we must use `NSRegularExpression`.

```
NSString *single = @"returning";
NSString *multiple = @"a man is returning home";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b",single];
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, multiple.length);
NSUInteger matched = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:multiple options:0 range:range];
NSLog(@"number of matched = %ld", matched);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSString`'s [`rangeOfString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) method:

```
NSRange range = [multiWordString rangeOfString:oneWordString];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
```

Comment: Oh, glad to see that. I was expecting the first answer to suggest using `NSRegularExpression`... :P

Comment: "Now you have two problems..." :-)

Answer (score 0):

The above code will return 1 if you are searching for "WAR" inside the longer "I AM AWARE". Maybe you're looking for entire word match.
In that case you should split the long string into an array of single words using...

```
NSArray *singleWords = [multiWordString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```

Then parse the array to find the **oneWordString**

Answer (score 0):

You can split up words in a string into an array using `[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]`. You can then check each word in the array to see if it matches the single word being searched. It's not the most efficient way, but it could work for your needs.